# How to filter the feed page of the Android app of Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, android-app-feed

I just installed the Stack Exchange app on my Android device. I'm quite new to that website.

I wanted to see discussions on the language I'm currently learning​, but all I see in the Feed activity page is questions on random topics. And there's no option anywhere on the app to modify that. How do I filter the feed section of this app?

Comment: Not possible. If you want any functionality other than reading existing posts or posting new questions/answers, you really better browse the site with a browser app on your device. You will get a mobile version which is quite easy to use. The app is lacking any real features, and will most likely be closed soon. (few months)

Comment: All right, thanks for the answer ! I'll go ahead and uninstall the app then.

Comment: No need to uninstall. It is still useful for posting, commenting, and getting notifications. Just saying don't expect any further features like filtering, searching, etc as they don't really exist there in the app.

Comment: Well I don't have use for this app without those functionalities. But thanks for the answer anyway.